# Slow boot with LVM on Juno

Tags: release-juno, boot

So I recently installed eOS with LVM checked at boot to use the whole disk. I've never had an issue on previous devices, but this one seems to be a bit less than happy.

`systemd-analyze` immediately makes it clear that this is not a userspace issue, as that is all handled incredibly quickly:

```
Startup finished in 35.868s (kernel) + 5.333s (userspace) = 41.201s
graphical.target reached after 2.118s in userspace
```

On checking `dmesg` I find a rather suspect output:

```
[    4.633861] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[   35.740814] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Seems to me that there is some issue with mounting the root partition, although my knowledge stops short of being able to diagnose why this is happening, or resolving the issue in any way.
I have heard that LVM can occasionally cause issues on some SSDs, which I suspect may well be the issue here, but I would rather avoid having to drop LVM if at all possible.

Any ideas where I might start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem but my loading times are even higher than yours:

```
Startup finished in 1.987s (firmware) + 25.210s (loader) + 37.081s (kernel) + 3.052s (userspace) 
= 1min 7.332s graphical.target reached after 3.041s in userspace
```

**I have found a solution here:**
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037457/slow-boot-with-ssd-and-lvm-on-new-install-of-18-04

Just use the First Method in the first reply. I'vr changed UUID to file path and used `wait_for_udev` instead of `wait-for-root` .

Now my loading time is:

```
Startup finished in 2.244s (firmware) + 2.808s (loader) + 5.160s (kernel) + 6.683s (userspace) 
= 16.897s graphical.target reached after 6.670s in userspace
```

Comment: Hm, I can't find anything particularly egregious with my own (426ms), but it's certainly not great either.

Comment: Confirming the first method alone worked for me, with no other alterations. Kernel boot considerably reduced to 4.889s with no observable detrimental effects to suspend, etc. Great find!